# go programming language bracket pair style

Tags: go

I'm just new to learn Go, when I try my first hello world with this style:

```
func main()
{
      ...somemagic...
}
```

and the 6g compiler says that's wrong.

But with this style:

```
func main(){
      ...somemagic...
}
```

That's OK.

Is the first bracket pair style illegal in Go?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062276/why-cant-i-put-the-opening-braces-on-the-next-line and possibly a bunch of other similar questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. That's a result of [automatic semicolon insertion](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Semicolons) in Go.

By the way, Go developers format their code using [`gofmt`](http://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) and follow that formatting.

Comment: Just to expand on this, the Go developers took this stance because it makes different codebases more consistent (in style), and even more importantly, a single code base more consistent. It also allows the developers to completely avoid the bikeshed-bait that is languages with flexible syntax rules, bickering over which way is the right/proper/correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first form can't work because of the [semicolon injection rules](http://weekly.golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Semicolons).